# trying to open gmail folders without javamail

Tags: java, imap, directory

So I have created a program without using javamail to connect with gmail imaps. I have managed to log in but I am struggling to find a way of opening folders. I have looked every and all the answers are javamail, which i'd rather not use as i was to learn this myself, however i cannot seem to find anything in the java api that will allow me to open this file without using javamail.

Here is my code:

```
public class CRole  {
    private BufferedReader socketSIn = null;
    private PrintWriter socketSOut = null;
    private Socket client;
    public CRole(){
         SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)   SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
         try {
                client = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("imap.gmail.com", 993);
        System.out.println("Connect to Host");

         }
         catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to listen on ports");
            System.exit(+1);
         }
     try {
            socketSIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            socketSOut = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
         } 
    catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Read failed");
            System.exit(+1);
         }
 }
   public void send_connectStringToS(String payload) {
    this.socketSOut.println(payload);
 }
   public String receive_acceptedStringFromS() {
    String line = "";
    try {
            line = this.socketSIn.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Input/Outpur error.");
           System.exit(+1);
    }
    return line;
}
```

There is more code but I don't think it is really required for this question. Basically, must I use javamail or is there an alternative?

Also is there a faster way to indent because when i use space bar it always comes out eschew.

Comment: If you are looking for an API, you guessed it, Javamail is the way to go. Otherwise, you could try to create your own implementation of IMAP, good luck with that.

Comment: If you really want to do it from scratch, the actual protocol is documented in RFC3501.

Comment: Yea, I've been reading it for a while and didn't understand what to do. However, it is much easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class Imaps  {
     private static BufferedReader in = null;
     private static PrintWriter out = null;
     private static Socket client;
     public static void main (String []arg){
    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    try {
        client = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("imap.gmail.com", 993);
        System.out.println("Connect to Host");

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to listen on ports");
        System.exit(+1);
    }
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("abcd CAPABILITY");
        String response =  (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);

        out.println("efgh STARTTLS"); //tls part does not work but will not cause any problems being there.
        response =  (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);

        String payload3 = "a001 login username @gmail.com password";
        out.println(payload3);

        response =  (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);
        response =  (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);
        response =  (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);
        //should say success if you enter correct password.


        String payload5 = "a002 select inbox";
        //String payload5 = "a002 select inbox";
        out.println(payload5);

        response =   (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);
        response =  (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);
        response =  (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);
        response =   (String) in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server: " + response);


    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Read failed");
        System.exit(+1);
    }
```

The answer is that you do not need to store the folder anywhere it is open when you send a002 select inbox. After this you can ask for any message that you want by using a004 fetch 1 body[text]. Note that the number one will fetch the very first email in your account and not the most recent.